# Example of ANY stochastic process (SDE), with reversible distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stationary-processes

Can anyone provide an example (as simple as they like) of a process $X_t$ on $\mathbb{R}$ solution to $dX=\sigma (X,t)dt+b(X,t)dW$. Where $W$ is a Brownian Motion, and $\sigma$ and $b$ can be any coefficients. 
And there exists a reversible distribution $\pi$ for $X$ defined in the usual way through the semi-group.

Any example will do, I don't know one.

---

Edit :

- The answerer is free to choose the SDE, the probability space, and the distribution $\pi$. But please can the solution to the SDE $X_t$ take values in $\mathbb{R}$.
- Please no degenerate answers, like a process which is deterministic.

Comment: Is $\pi$ given or can the answerer pick it too?

Comment: @Ian answerer can pick it. Im just looking for a solution to an sde, for which there exists a reversible distribution. Any will do, something as 'close' (in some sense of the word :) )  to Brownian motion as possible would be best.  I don't want some degenerate case where everything is deterministic.